# C++ Sleep functions

Tags: c++, windows-10, sleep

I am trying to execute a sleep function that is somewhat accurate. I measured how long my sleep function slept for and put them side by side. The format for the samples down below are: "expected ms:outcome ms".

I have tried many options and I still can't find a solution. Here are the routes I tried:

#### Route 1

```
Sleep(<time>)
```

```
/* milliseconds */
38.4344 46.4354
41.728 47.7818
0.556 0.0012
43.6532 46.8087
0.4523 0.0009
62.8664 76.995
1.5363 15.4592
75.9435 78.1663
91.5194 92.0786
0.6533 0.001
39.7423 45.6729
0.5022 0.0008
54.7837 60.597
0.4248 0.0011
39.2165 45.6977
0.4854 0.0008
10.6741 15.054
```

- Had little to no noticeable CPU usage which is good but still inaccurate results.

#### Route 2

```
/* Windows sleep in 100ns units */
BOOLEAN nanosleep(LONGLONG ns){
    /* Declarations */
    HANDLE timer;   /* Timer handle */
    LARGE_INTEGER li;   /* Time defintion */
    /* Create timer */
    if(!(timer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL)))
        return FALSE;
    /* Set timer properties */
    li.QuadPart = -ns;
    if(!SetWaitableTimer(timer, &li, 0, NULL, NULL, FALSE)){
        CloseHandle(timer);
        return FALSE;
    }
    /* Start & wait for timer */
    WaitForSingleObject(timer, INFINITE);
    /* Clean resources */
    CloseHandle(timer);
    /* Slept without problems */
    return TRUE;
}
```

```
/* milliseconds */
1.057 14.7561
66.5977 79.4437
0.409 14.7597
152.053 156.757
1.26725 15.747
19.025 30.6343
67.3235 78.678
0.4203 14.4713
65.3507 74.4703
0.4525 14.8102
28.6145 29.7099
72.0035 74.7315
0.5971 14.8625
55.7059 59.3889
0.4791 14.5419
50.9913 61.6719
0.5929 15.5558
```

- Had low CPU usage which was good but was still inaccurate.
- I had read somewhere that using MultiMedia Timers would provide accurate sleep.

[Code Source](https://gist.github.com/Youka/4153f12cf2e17a77314c)

#### Route 3

```
void super_sleep(double ms)
{
    auto a = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while ((std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - a) < std::chrono::milliseconds(static_cast<int>(ms))) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

```
/* milliseconds */
55.7059 55.0006
0.5669 0.0008
66.5977 66.0009
0.4213 0.0009
0.7228 0.0007
7.5374 7.0006
0.8825 0.0007
0.4143 0.0009
59.8062 59.0005
51.7157 51.0006
54.0807 54.0006
11.8834 11.0006
65.3507 65.0004
14.429 14.0006
0.4452 0.0012
1.6797 1.0004
96.0012 96.0006
```

- Worked a lot better than the other attempts but uses up to 7% of my CPU.

---

I also tried using `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` and received similar result to Route 2.

I am on Windows 10 20H2, C++17 and i9 9900k.

Comment: To get guaranteed CPU realtime metrics one needs to use a special purpose, dedicated, realtime operating system if you want your program to sleep for an "accurate" amount of time. Microsoft Windows is not a realtime operating system.

Comment: Windows 10 is not a real time operating system. And even real time operating systems are not perfectly accurate. What do you want to achieve. And second question, what's really needed to be achieved (often less then developers aim for)

Comment: Rough outline - `Sleep` gives up the thread's time-slice and suspends it.  The thread will only be woken up when at least the amount of time requested has passed (or greater).  If their is no processor available to run the thread it will get queued until one is available.  Some background here: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2020/10/04/windows-timer-resolution-the-great-rule-change/

Comment: I used this [Timer](https://github.com/GiovanniDicanio/StopwatchWin32/blob/master/Stopwatch/Stopwatch.h) which claims to use the Win32 high-performance/resolution timers API. My code looks like 
`win32::Stopwatch t;

t.Start();

Sleep(delay_entry.second + slope);

t.Stop();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get *pretty* good accuracy (but not perfect since Windows isn't a Real Time OS), is to use one of the standard sleep functions, but sleep short - and then busy-wait the remaining time. That usually keeps the CPU usage low.

```
template<class T, class U>
void Sleep(std::chrono::duration<T,U> ss) {
    auto target = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + ss; // the target end time

    // Sleep short. 5 ms is just an example. You need to trim that parameter.
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(target - std::chrono::milliseconds(5));

    // busy-wait the remaining time
    while(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() < target) {}
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try and then update you, thank you

Comment: @Clawifier Ok. Remember to trim those 5 milliseconds. The idea is that it should _always_ wake up when `now() < target` is `true`, otherwise the accuracy won't be as good as it can be.

Comment: This provided a much more accurate Sleep while maintaining CPU usage, thank you!